# Delete based on Computer time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

How I could delete data based on my computer time? For example I want at 06.59 (my computer time) all data in table1 deleted. I think I could use C# with sqlclient, but I don't know how it's work

Comment: C# might be overkill, wouldn't this do what you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Comment: You can directly deal with SQL Job..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187910.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple application which deletes the data using C# and ADO .NET, or Linq-to-SQL etc... just like you said. You could then set the application to run using the Windows scheduler (I am assuming you are running Windows and not MONO on Linux etc...).

The official Microsoft guides on how to schedule tasks:

For Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569?wa=wsignin1.0

For Windows 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task